# How to group lists and evaluate mean square error?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, group-by, mean-square-error

I'm writing custom metric function and here's the steps I implemented:

1. I have a list of floats in `preds` and list of `int` `0-1` values in `target`
2. I round `preds`
3. I need to make `groupby` on `preds`
4. Count mean `target` values for those groupedby `preds`
5. Count `MSE` between groupedby `preds` and `target`

That's how `df` looks like before `groupby`

[image]

```
rounded = [np.round(x, 2) for x in preds]

df = pd.DataFrame({'target': target, 'preds': rounded})
        
df = df.groupby('preds')['target'].mean().to_frame().reset_index()
        
mse = mean_squared_error(df['target'], df['preds'])
```

And that's how after `groupby` and `mean()` (as I can't properly display `groupby`)

[image]

**Basicaly, I don't know how to groupby on two python `list`s.**

I did groupby on one list like that

`gr_list = [list(j) for i, j in groupby(rounded)]`

But I have no clue how to groupby second list, based on `gr_list` groupping

Comment: Hi, could you show what `df.head()` looks like before groupby, and also what the expected result should look like?

Comment: @Laurent, I took screenshots. I guess the question is, how to make standart groupby in DataFrame but on two seperate lists

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest code, but I managed to do it like that:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(rounded): # rounded is rounded preds
    d[item].append(target[i])
```

[image]

```
meanDict = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    meanDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
```

[image]

```
preds, target = zip(*avgDict.items())

mse = mean_squared_error(values, keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example of a more idiomatic way to do what you are trying to achieve, if I understand correctly:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

preds = [random.random() for _ in range(1_000)]
target = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(1_000)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"preds": preds, "target": target})
```

```py
import numpy as np

# Steps 1 to 4 of your post
df = df.round({"preds": 2}).groupby("preds").agg(np.mean).reset_index()

print(df)
# Output
     preds    target
0     0.00  1.000000
1     0.01  0.555556
2     0.02  0.375000
3     0.03  0.375000
4     0.04  0.416667
..     ...       ...
96    0.96  0.666667
97    0.97  0.500000
98    0.98  0.375000
99    0.99  0.461538
100   1.00  0.285714
```

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Step 5
print(mean_squared_error(df["preds"], df["target"]))  # 0.1084811098077257
```